# What is the owner of literal reference such as &4 in Rust?

Tags: pointers, reference, rust

Normally, there is only one owner for a specific value (except for things like `Rc<T>`). Then what is the owner of the value `4` below since the variable `myVar` borrows it from something? I want to know what is that something.

```
let myVar = &4;
```

Comment: It does not belong to anything. `&4` is just a reference to something. In this case a reference to some memory location where a 4 is.

Comment: It is static. There is no owner because it is in static memory so exists for the duration of the application.

Comment: Alternatively, you could think of it as being 'owned' by the program itself.

Comment: all above make senses, and being 'owned' by the program itself makes me clear. Thanks all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Literals, be they:

- number literals, like `4`
- string literals, like `"Hello, World"`

Have a `'static` lifetime as their value is hard-coded into the library or executable itself. For example, on Linux, they would be found either in the `.text` segment or the `.rodata` segment of the ELF binary.

In that sense, you can think of them as being owned by the program itself.